# Reverse/Swap halfway

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, reverse, swap

To reverse a whole `vector` there exists `std::reverse`. But I would like to "divide" a vector in two part (exactly in the middle) and reverse both, put them back together and reverse the whole `vector` again. For example we have:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Than divide it in two parts and reverse both:

`0 1 2 3` -> `3 2 1 0`   and `4 5 6 7`-> `7 6 5 4`, put the reversed parts together `3 2 1 0 7 6 5 4` and reverse again: `4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3`.

I tried with `reverse_copy` but this wasn't successful. Here's my code snippet:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator mid = nr.begin() + nr.size() / 2;
std::vector<int>::iterator midLast = nr.size() / 2 + nr.end();
vector<int> temp1, temp2;
std::reverse_copy(nr.begin(),mid, std::begin(temp1));
std::reverse_copy(midLast, nr.end(), std::begin(temp2));
std::reverse(temp1.begin(), temp2.end());
```

How could I implement my approach? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are an odd number of elements?

Comment: Amusingly, this is often given as a possible "clever" implementation of [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate), which achieves exactly what you want.

Comment: @RichardCritten than the middle element should stay alway in the middle of the `vector`.

Comment: `nr.size() / 2 + nr.end()` is far beyond `nr.end()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::reverse(nr.begin(), nr.begin() + nr.size() / 2 );
std::reverse(nr.begin() + nr.size() / 2 + ((nr.size() % 2) != 0 ? 1 : 0), nr.end());
std::reverse(nr.begin(), nr.end());

for (auto& it : nr)
{
    std::cout << it << " ";
}
```

Output for `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`

```
5 6 7 8 4 0 1 2 3
```

Output for `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`

```
4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the missing final reverse. Edit: crossed edit... my adding was deleted.

Comment: @FilipKočica the first `std::reverse` works fine, but at the second one I suddenly get only second number? How is this possible?

Comment: Both examples works for me, what exactly seems wrong?

Comment: now my comment isn't there anymore. :( 
For odd numbers like `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` the output is: `6 7 8 0 1 2 3 4 5 `. 
@FilipKočica Thanks!

Comment: @Unnamed Lol iam dumb, i used `/` instead of `%`... Now it works correctly.

Comment: This `(nr.size() % 2) != 0 ? 1 : 0` could be written more simply with `nr.size() % 2` since `x%2` can only take the values 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

The task can be done with using standard algorithm `std::swap_ranges`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    std::swap_ranges(v.begin(), std::next(v.begin(), v.size() / 2),
        std::prev(v.end(), v.size() / 2));

    for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3
```

Otherwise you can use just `std::reverse` instead of the algorithm `std::reverse_copy`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::reverse(v.begin(), std::next(v.begin(), v.size() / 2));
    std::reverse(std::prev(v.end(), v.size() / 2), v.end());

    for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
3 2 1 0 7 6 5 4
4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This version will cope with an odd number of elements (leaving the middle one unmoved)

```
 auto size = nr.size();
 auto begin = nr.begin();
 auto end = nr.end();
 std::reverse(begin, begin + size/2);
 std::reverse(begin + size/2 + (size%2), end);
 std::reverse(begin, end);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by BoBTFish, this is what std::rotate does.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void printVector(const std::vector<int>& aVector)
{
    for (auto& val : aVector)
    {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
} 

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> intVect{0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

    printVector(intVect);

    std::rotate(intVect.begin(), intVect.begin() + intVect.size() / 2, intVect.end());

    printVector(intVect);

    return 0;
}
```

This will output the desired result:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3

Comment: std::rotate does not work when the number of elements is odd. The middle element shall not be moved.